# Is this some sort of hacker attack?

Tags: .htaccess, undefined-behavior

I'm using a tool on my website that detects any error and sends me an email when a code error happens. Recently, I've received some requests not allowed on my IP **- not url -** where only GET is allowed.

The requests all come from the IP `173.187.177.22` and, besides happening once a minute or two, have a strange input. Here's a few examples of the input passed on three different requests:

```
array(1) {
  ["QqIKyIubMeV_mOiW6N7CL6c1rCSY9W1cSlveqfTb9P9cpfwTTOL1sOUdhvIphPNeVGdeKl9lhHf7ADk9gLNgePAZdO/ygtxofmT/sfbFyrBKzGvrWRVL6kT2zbkVrV1dOXIQkhDuUUpacUnKuaPkB78z85jmqjY1l7hXnLIONUtctt679mbW9KPHoq1ozFK6Ki1hfN9WnwnaN14akSGWZkDfoVDFdrneVf4JDOlfY3r78Gp39bueUaHn6aMEAGys3MEEjr4ghbHe0T6MURgQyHZHoV1olgRiAo5xRjChrhjD7w/pYaaNi0_6DKHMJBS7H9_bw8I/qaOoFy/EeO4G3QFiIlpcutIEf62YOwlk53MzuuLM5eje9I_TUXc9XmC/kU9EX2QDYYT9wGmg3w/7YJSOIIgi"]=>
  NULL
}

array(1) {
  ["RfZWlNmbZ3O21/tLFs9AFHaO5zr9g/FArn8djhJGYhqs32THrVCnqDI/xUAJcg0DGKi6a/FEz7PzB7GWu72B7uA3ZvdKfNUhSCZR39If6oOCATHN9VYgzYJQfDaPrcqJh3IBaHPcJSgUXsv_amGKAd6AJ675AtCvMfdYUQk5V/Pc1X2LR2M7uDfEW1Mv2S9mHSZSLYV_cDAJFOavCtxfyLQms3kOudm_arsbkn2kQbh1LvaC0iP0aDSfmmEmtFIX_rmMwSGFghPV1mZtELD6NEjuorMwix70CvGi/g27CRmU0qtuVwwlhf67Qi7cZBNCOzAb_mFMfUnp1E4kWhbvIpNyo_c0TuwM_BNRKm9UQc8rdWPk8CmN"]=>
  NULL
}

array(1) {
  ["RfFelN_ZbKsBnezpI20p0My0Rd7Gzx4bNeu9iTNNiizOsqFE_uCyvsWkg_zvep1KlWlp9fTNSImM9hitT/Zrs/UvxMgTp1llGwg1a3WinrqPXZSySmQkaU7WXXHHf/_sWk1OcEp6PfFXczId60vlvr9X7OTVlNDLW7oET38xmCV0Q7sL_s/iLlilTAHIh7ICTxqOTzO2ONFFpcqy/wD6Hw4TEFiS1g6APil_/aJkbd/My6ESB4jXehj3HhEbLUWVRsQlJa6cCVKJpwieEAiZCi/N2EgaEd3jxRdKrIA75VgVPteDdqaSnPUljHXerCMic2UzVfLqWvK4w8beTnoKnQacmJf8c6ANr8l3fU2pQn7zmqdzO/LL6MNsbVF0B0G9iFm0x9fO0cuN8MUW5IlI289ILTvpLpJL2Qg6QQ"]=>
  string(1) "="
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should put in place to prevent this kind of behavior? In the past I've blocked the IPs responsible for this from `.htaccess`, but ideally I don't want to continue blocking IPs manually since if it is some sort of attack it could bypass IP

Comment: I think you should ask this question over at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've copied the question there, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Or possibly over at Webmasters.SE. But see how it goes over at Security first.

Comment: I've chosen to catch this behavior and `exit()`... I think it should do